# How to calculate Restcall Response time on Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

For me it is very strange that jmeter does not bring response time for restcall.

These are all possibilites to be saved on jtl/csv file:

```
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
#jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
# Save ResponseData for failed samples
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=true
```

My question is either if response time is equal one of the data above or if I can manually calculate sum some values and get to it.

PS: The reason while I don't simply use Jmeter Response Time graph is due to the fact that I send data to Datadog (measurement tool) instead.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if it's ok, you should accept answer and upvote so that users can trust it as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Response time is in **time** field.

There is an additional metric **latency** which provides time to first byte.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html

You might also want to read :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html